# How to add language parametr to NumeralTickFormatter in HoverTool in bokeh

Tags: python, bokeh

Let's assume we have the following constructor for HoverTool in bokeh:

```py
hover = HoverTool(tooltips=[("min_temp", "@{min}{0,0.0}°C")])
```

By default, this creates a tooltip where numbers for the value "min_temp" use comma as a thousand separator and dot for decimals - for example, `10,000.123`. However, I want to use spaces to separate thousands instead of a comma, that is `10 000.123`.

From what I understand from the documentation, [HoverTool](https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/tools.html#formatting-tooltip-fields) uses the [NumeralTickFormatter](https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/reference/models/formatters.html#bokeh.models.NumeralTickFormatter) class in bokeh to format numerals, and this class supports the language parametr, but I have no idea how can I change that from the HoverTool strings (besides rewriting the parametr in source code). I think this could solve my problem.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how to set the "language" in the `NumeralTickFormatter` but you can make use of the `CustomJSHover` and create you own rule with a few lines.

**Minimal Example**

```
from bokeh.plotting import figure, output_notebook, show
from bokeh.models import HoverTool, CustomJSHover
output_notebook()

p = figure(plot_width=400, plot_height=400, title=None)
x = [999.5, 1000.7, 1001.0]
y = [2, 5, 3]
p.circle(x, y, size=10)
custom = CustomJSHover(code=
    '''
    var num =  special_vars.x.toFixed(2).toString()
    var splitted = num.split(".")
    for (var i=splitted[0].length-3; 0<i; i-=3){
      num = num.slice(0,i)+" "+num.slice(i)
    }
    return num
    ''')

p.add_tools(HoverTool(
    tooltips=[('x','$x{custom}' )],
    formatters={'$x':custom}
))

show(p)
```

**Output**
[image: HoverTool with whitespace to separate thousands]